# Setting a wallpaper through an intent

Tags: java, android

I have the following code wherein a dialog is created with a 'Set wallpaper' button. I already have the image to be set as a `bitmap`, the question is how do I set the wallpaper through an intent?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_image_black_24dp).setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo_2))
                    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_wallpaper_black_24dp, "Set as wallpaper", //WHAT GOES HERE)
                    .setContentTitle("Saved screenshot")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle().bigPicture(bitmap));
```

0 knowledge about intents, pending intents, and what not.

Comment: Do you mean the wallpaper of the **application** or the wallpaper of the **home screen** ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code, but manually you have to chose set as wallpaper option

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmap);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(shareIntent);
```